# Splash screen with XML drawable as window background misaligned

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

I added a splash screen to my Android app by using an XML drawable as a window background inside the theme.

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Here is the code for the drawable:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/white"/>

<item>

    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_icon"/>
</item>
```

I need the splash screen to continuously be shown even after the second activity was loaded because it first needs to load some data from firebase. That's why I added the same drawable to the parent view of the second activity.

The problem I face is that the icon on the splash screen is aligned slightly higher than in the second activity, even though I used:

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true">`

Is there an easy way to fix this problem?

Comment: Why not to have a "SplashScreenActivity" and the activity is in charge of retrieving the data? The UI if this Activity is only your drawable. Then when the data are loaded it redirects to the home screen (or whatever screen you want to display).

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that. The problem I always had was finding a good way to pass all that data to the next activity, because I have to access different kinds of objects not just Strings and Ints

Comment: What you can do is to create a singleton and use it to store your data. So like that you can access it across your app and you don't need your data classes to implement Parcelable as you don't put your data into an Intent. The other (better) option is to use a dependency injection framework like Dagger2. With this solution you can do the same thing (having a separated cache class) but Dagger will take care of the lifetime of the cache.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at both solutions!